# How to get first and last names having 6 characters long using regular expression in linux

Tags: regex

I want to find all the names having first and last names 6 characters long only.
I have write this `grep '^.{6},.{6}$' names.txt` but it is not giving any output. The names are written in file names.txt.
Sample ->
firstname,lastname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using basic regular expressions, you have to escape the curly braces.

Using you pattern, you can add `-E` for extended regular expressions so you don't have to escape them.

```
grep -E '^.{6},.{6}$' names.txt
```

---

**Note** that a dot in the pattern can also match a space or a comma, so the pattern could also match:

`,,,,,,,,,,,,,` or      `,`

You could update the pattern to match 6 times any character except for spaces, tab or a comma using a negated character class `[^,[:blank:]]`

```
grep -E '^[^,[:blank:]]{6},[^,[:blank:]]{6}$' names.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```sh
grep '^.\{6\},.\{6\}$' names.txt
```

Comment: Nice!  Please consider though that code only answers are usually frowned upon as it may not be clear to everyone why this answer works.  It is helpful to provide a small explanation.

Comment: I have also written the same code but without \. Can you please explain what is the use of \